Every time while loading website it is loading one or two times
I'm using angular + scully  every time while loading website its loading one or two time how to fixed this is issue.
give me solution for this im using angular with scully. where I need to fix this issue in angular . what would be the issue of that give me correct solutions. how to remove postRenderer
import { ScullyConfig } from '@scullyio/scully';
import '@scullyio/scully-plugin-puppeteer';
import './scully/plugins/passport-plugin';
import './scully/plugins/visa-details-plugin';
import './scully/plugins/pages-plugin';


/** this loads the default render plugin, remove when switching to something else. */

let executablePath = '';
console.log('process.platform:', process.platform)
switch (process.platform) {
  case 'win32':
   // executablePath = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe';
    executablePath = 'C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe';
    break;
  case 'linux':
    executablePath = '/usr/bin/chromium-browser';
    break;
  case 'darwin':
    executablePath = '/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome';
    break;
  default:
    console.error(`Unsupported platform: ${process.platform}`);
    process.exit(1);
}

export const config: ScullyConfig = {
  puppeteerLaunchOptions: {
    executablePath: executablePath,
    headless: true,
    args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'],
  },
  projectRoot: "./src",
  projectName: "travels-website",
  spsModulePath: 'YOUR OWN MODULE PATH HERE',
  distFolder: './www', // output directory of your Angular build artifacts
  outDir: './dist/static', // directory for scully build artifacts
  defaultPostRenderers: ['copyAssets'],
  routes: {
    '/details-page/:livinCountryCode/:visaCountryCode/:productName': {
      type: 'visaDetailsPlugin',
    },
    '/passport/:productId/:productName': {
      type: 'passportPlugin',
    },
    '/pages/details/:id/:name': {
      type: 'pagesPlugin',
      postRenderers: ['contentFolder'],
    }
  }
};


